# Searching an user in a dict inside a list

Tags: python

Assuming the sample file 'data.txt', where:

```
NAME   COLOR   INDEX   DEBIT
Leo    blue    1       40
Mike   orange  2       55
Don    purple  3       32
Raph   red     4       21
```

If I need to find Leo and sum 12 to his debt, which is the best way to do that?

I'm trying to figure out how do I, for an example, check like "if user[name] is in users".

I already have done:

```
data = open('data.txt','r')

index = data.readline().split()
index1 = index[0]
index2 = index[1]
index3 = index[2]
index4 = index[3]

users = list()

for line in data.readlines():
    value = line.split()
    user = dict()
    user[index1] = value[0]
    user[index2] = value[1]
    user[index3] = value[2]
    user[index4] = value[3]
    users.append(user)

print(users)
```

Where I create the dicts and append it in the list.

I need to change my original archive to sum new values to the column debit.

Btw, thank you very much for your help. I'm learning by myself how to manipulate files using python. :)

Comment: Are you trying to add 12 to debit where name is leo?

Comment: @ParijatBhatt yeap! Thats an example, I'm trying to learn how to do that with any user, add 12 to Leo, or 4 to Don, yadda yadda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to go the route you have started...you can try something like:

```
names = [i['NAME'] for i in users] #get list of names
keys = users[0].keys() #get list of keys

name = 'Leo' #name of entry to change
loc = names.index(name) #location of this entry in the original list "users"

for u in users: #convert numbers to floats so you can add to them (or int works)
    for k in keys:
        try:
            u[k]=float(u[k])
        except:
            pass

users[loc]['DEBIT']+=12 #finally, add desired value to this entry
```

pandas is much easier however if you read in your file correctly

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use pandas, you could do like this

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep=" ", header=None)
df.columns = ["name", "color", "index", "debit"]
index = df[df['name']==name].index
df.loc[index,'debit']+=12
```

Comment: It's not working :( I'm trying to read about this "pandas"
I installed it and imported, but getting weird (for me) errors

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the error. It's always good to handle data with pandas as it makes life very easy

Comment: Try this to read data : pd.read_csv('data.txt', error_bad_lines=False,sep=" ", header=None)

Comment: Where do I declare df? I get "NameError: name 'df' is not defined".

Comment: df is the dataframe name into which you store the data by reading the csv files.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data.txt', sep='\t', index_col='NAME')
df.loc['Leo','DEBIT']+=12
```

Comment: I copied and pasted your data into data.txt...this should work for you

Comment: paste it into excel and re-save is as a tab delimited text file..then my code will work (made edit)

Comment: honestly dont know what to say..it works for me..make sure your data is separated into different columns before saving it